# Probabilty distribution kernel with $x^x$ component

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Is there any probability distribution family (or similar) for a continuous random variable $X$ with this type of kernel:

$$p(x;\beta,p) \propto \frac{x^{xp}}{\Gamma_p(x)}e^{-\beta x}$$

where $p \in \mathrm{N}_+$ and $\beta > p$ are parameters and $\Gamma_p(\cdot)$ is the $p$-multivariate gamma function,

$$\Gamma_p(x) = \prod_{j=1}^p \Gamma \left( x-\frac{j-1}{2}\right)$$

with $\Gamma(\cdot)$ being the gamma function.

Comment: What is the domain of $x$, all reals or just non-negative?

Comment: The domain is $x > \frac{p-1}{2}$. This restriction on domain is necessary because of the $\Gamma_p$ function form.